# Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

So I don't know what I clicked on but after I did, everything, like literally everything stopped working.

Current error message:

> ERROR: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be
>   caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an
>   unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the User Manual
>   chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Process
>   command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe
>   -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=NL -Duser.language=nl -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\MSahl.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx\gradle-5.4.1\lib\gradle-launcher-5.4.1.jar
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.4.1 Please read
>   the following process output to find out more:
>   ----------------------- Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Even after uninstalling everything the problem still persists.

Comment: In the Gradle wrapper properties, you'll need to reduce -Xmx1536m

Comment: @cricket_007 that line is a default given line, its already added and doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Your value is `-Xmx1536m`, the VM needs at least `1572864KB`. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169849/3999808

Comment: I'm saying you need to lower it. According to https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html - the default is only 512m

Comment: Following OneCricketeer's advice, I lowered to 512m and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

add this line into `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

then clean and rebuild project

Comment: The problem persists even when opening a normal default android project, it automatically jumps straight to the error. It can't build the gradle. That line is a default line in said default projects.

Comment: check it gradel.propertis and replace this with yours

Comment: what you told me is a default line, its already written in the gradle properties. Which means it doesn't fix the problem even when replacing it with what you gave me, its the same thing.

Comment: `gradle.properties` not `gradel.properties`

Comment: Also, is good to remember that if it's greater than 2Gb, it's necessary to install the 64-bit Java

Answer (score 1):

Open gradle.properties:
Max limit from Gradle 5.4.1 document:
If the requested build environment does not specify a maximum heap size, the Daemon will use up to 512MB of heap.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
Or you can remark memory setting. The system will set by itself.

The rest of content of my file:
======================================================================
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
======================================================================
Now, File >> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 1):

My Android Studio was working fine. But executing Gradle from command line gave this same error 'could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-1572864kb-object-heap'

Looks like, it was because Gradle couldn't find java

Defined JAVA_HOME system variable, pointing to the same path Android studio was using.
(get it from Studio > project structure > SDK Location > JDK Location)

Worked for me.

Comment: To confirm - this was my problem. JAVA_HOME was not set.

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Android Studio, JDK location has been moved to Gradle Settings.

Answer (score 0):

restoring my system to an earlier date resolved the issue. it was an update to the jdk the cause

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Enter to run highlighted section in android studio.