# Android Studio - task needs to be manually killed to make code changes effective

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment

Code changes are deployed correctly into the Android device. However, they are actually applied only if I kill the task associated to the app on the device either by 1) swiping it away in the "recent apps view" or 2) by first clicking on the "stop" button in Android Studio, to make sure the task is killed, and only then on the "play" button.

This behavior occurs on multiple devices, with all apps and systematically on older Android versions and only sometimes on newer versions.

Solutions tried so far:

- Invalidating the cache / restart...
- Clean / rebuild project code
- Unchecking / checking the "Force stop running application before launching activity..." option

Does anyone know a solution or how I can find out what the problem is?

Comment: Are you running it from a custom `Run/Debug Configuration`? I was thinking maybe in the `Miscallaneous` tab you have not checked the `Force stop running application before launching activity` or some other setting probably...

Comment: I had tried with that option both unchecked and checked, but no luck

Comment: Are you clicking the "Green Play" button?

Comment: I just improved my question to provide more info

Comment: And what are the "code changes" you don't see for example?

Comment: Any code change, because the older version of the app is launched the first time.

Comment: ok, to rule out any AStudio issue, try from the command line/terminal emulator of your choice: `./gradlew clean installDebug` from your project's root.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Indeed, I got an error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. [...] Error occurred during initialization of VM: Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap. The same error occurred to this user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169350/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-1572864kb-object-heap-android-studio

Comment: Seems like the build process is indeed failing, have you tried allocating more memory to the Java Heap? (As suggested there?)

Comment: So, I fixed the error by actually decreasing the maximum memory for the JVM (from org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m to org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m). However, the weird behavior described in the question where the old task with the old code is not replaced by the new version of the app in the device still occurs

Comment: I think you ought to give it *more* memory, not less :) (come by the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210228/android-help) if you want, I am going to be there for a few more minutes today.